# javascript: understanding how nested for works

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

starting from this chapter of this book: http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html ("paragraph named layout a table")
i'm trying to understand how the code works and today i'm studying a particular script containing nested for.
So starting with an object line that:

```
function TextCell(text){
 this.text = text.split('\n')

}
```

the book shows this:

```
  var rows = [];
for (var i=0; i<5;i++){
  var row = [];
  for (var j=0;j<5;j++){
    if ((j+i)%2==0)
      row.push(new TextCell("##"));
    else
      row.push(new TextCell(" "));


  }
  rows.push(row)
}
```

the result will be an array (of length 5) of arrays (each of lenght 5).
Every inner array containig 5 TextCell object (each of them cointainig text attribute with value another array (lenght 1) that contains "##" or " "

Now i need to understand how nested for works:

In this case we have 5x5 operations rigth?

```
So first step i=0:
  we create row=[] //that is empty
  start the inner for:
    j=0 so i+j=0 that is an even number so we push inside row "##"
```

Now what happen next? we remains in the inner loop (so i is still 0 and j=1)? and we will procede in this way (we still remaining in the inner loop: so i=0 and j=1; i=0 and j=2 etc, then when j get to 5, we pass to outer loop and so i=1 and j=0,i=1 and j=1 etc)

I hope i've explain myself well, my reasoning is correct? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah your logic seems pretty correct to me :)

Comment: `for (var j=0;j<5;j++){ console.log(i,j);`

Comment: yes you right!! should i have think this before, thanks